# Assigning NSDateComponents to a label

Tags: swift

I'm creating a mobile app that has a countdown to a specific date. I think I have the timer itself correct, but I'm struggling to get it into a format where I can assign it to my label. I'm getting an error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(NSDateComponents)'. This error is found at the line "var date = String(openingGavelDate)". The outlet for the label has been properly created in this file.

First step I took was creating the date variable and setting it equal to the converted value of my other variable. Second step involved trying to look through documentation but so far I haven't really found any substantial documentation that can help.

```
func createGavelTimer() {
    let openingGavelDate = NSDateComponents()
    openingGavelDate.year = 2019
    openingGavelDate.month = 7
    openingGavelDate.day = 16
    openingGavelDate.hour = 14
    openingGavelDate.minute = 00
    openingGavelDate.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "CST")! as TimeZone
    var date = String(openingGavelDate) //problem is here
    countdownLabel.text = date
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions:

```
let date = Calendar.current.date(from: openingGavelDate)

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CST")!


    let yourString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: FYI - No need to set the formatter's `timeZone` to `TimeZone.current` since that is the default.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the comment. This is just a sample. I will change it into question-like.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents) object to a [`Date`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) by using [`Calendar.date(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292916-date), and then converting that to a `String` using a [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter):

```swift
let gregorianCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

if let date = gregorianCalendar.date(from: openingGavelDate as DateComponents) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

    countdownLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Also, as @Sh_Khan and @rmaddy have commented, you should be using `DateComponents`, `TimeZone`, etc. instead of their `NS` counterparts (unless you're using Swift 2 or lower).

Comment: Use DateFormatter do display dates. Don't just use default string conversion.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for the suggestion, I forgot about `DateFormatter`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to do to form your date:

1. Set a calendar on the DateComponents instance.
2. Get your date by accessing the `date` property on your DateComponents instance.

Also, I'd recommend using time zone identifiers instead of abbreviation to specify a time zone; advantage is that identifiers will automatically apply special rules such as daylight savings as appropriate.  (Below I've substituted the "America/Chicago" zone for UTC.)

Try this code in a playground:

```
var openingGavelDate = DateComponents()
let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Chicago")!
openingGavelDate.year = 2019
openingGavelDate.month = 7
openingGavelDate.day = 16
openingGavelDate.hour = 14
openingGavelDate.minute = 00
openingGavelDate.calendar = Calendar.current
openingGavelDate.timeZone = timeZone
let date = openingGavelDate.date
print(date ?? "no date")
```

Output: `2019-07-16 19:00:00 +0000` (your date in GMT.)

This will get you a date, but notice that the Date class prints in GMT by default, because `Date` has no concept of timezone.

To print `date` in the timezone and format you want, use `DateFormatter`:

```
let f = DateFormatter()
f.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
f.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Chicago")!
print(f.string(from: date!))
```

Output: `2019-07-16 02:00 PM` (your date & time, in CST and formatted for reading.)

DateFormatter allows you to either control the format yourself, or follow the user's system settings to determine what is in the final string.  See the docs for `DateFormatter` to see how to get it into the format you want to display.

Comment: Your date format is wrong. Never use `YYYY`. Use `yyyy`. And avoid specifying a fixed `dateFormat`. Use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` whenever you show a date to a user so it is properly localized.

Comment: It's also best to avoid creating timezones with an abbreviation. They are not unique. But why set the timezone at all? Why not show the date in local time?

Comment: @rmaddy Date format string and timezone creation are updated.

Comment: I leave it to the asker to determine how to format the date.  I have presented dates both ways (exact format string or locale-based styles) depending on the context.

Comment: No, you only show one way to format a `Date`. The `print` doesn't count since that is never a valid way to show a `Date` to a user.

Comment: @rmaddy time zone comes in to play because this app is being targeted to people all across the country, when the specified time in the countdown is in Central time. There's a really high chance I'm doing this wrong as I'm a self-taught beginner to Swift but it seemed like something to go for since it should in theory count down to any user no matter where they are

Comment: @GregUctum If the components you are setting are specific to a fixed timezone, then it makes sense to set that timezone when converting the components to a `Date`. Whether you use that same timezone or not when converting the resulting `Date` to a string that you display to the user depends on what you wish to show to the user.